# Running sum that only increases on rows when a condition is met to create a flag

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like the following:

| GroupName | Year | CutOff | RunningTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | 2013 | 125 | 30 |
| G1 | 2014 | 125 | 95 |
| G1 | 2015 | 125 | 149 |
| G1 | 2016 | 125 | 202 |
| G1 | 2017 | 125 | 228 |
| G1 | 2018 | 125 | 253 |
| G1 | 2019 | 125 | 273 |
| G1 | 2020 | 125 | 289 |
| G1 | 2021 | 125 | 320 |
| G1 | 2022 | 125 | 337 |
| G1 | 2023 | 125 | 408 |
| G2 | 2013 | 100 | 42 |

And so on. I am trying to use a running sum to flag rows where the RunningTotal value is greater than the CutOff value for the first time, or greater than the CutOff value plus the previous greater RunningTotal value. So I would be looking for a query output like this:

| GroupName | Year | CutOff | RunningTotal | NewSum | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | 2013 | 125 | 30 | 125 | 0 |
| G1 | 2014 | 125 | 95 | 125 | 0 |
| G1 | 2015 | 125 | 149 | 274 | 1 |
| G1 | 2016 | 125 | 202 | 274 | 0 |
| G1 | 2017 | 125 | 228 | 274 | 0 |
| G1 | 2018 | 125 | 253 | 274 | 0 |
| G1 | 2019 | 125 | 273 | 274 | 0 |
| G1 | 2020 | 125 | 289 | 414 | 1 |
| G1 | 2021 | 125 | 320 | 414 | 0 |
| G1 | 2022 | 125 | 337 | 414 | 0 |
| G1 | 2023 | 125 | 408 | 414 | 0 |
| G2 | 2013 | 100 | 42 | 100 | 0 |

I haven’t been able to figure out how to flag this correctly so far. The closest I’ve gotten is flagging the first time the RunningTotal has increased beyond an integer multiple of the CutOff column. Does anyone have any suggestions here? I’m working in SQL Server Management Studio.

Also, maybe something to note: CutOff is not necessarily constant among each GroupName. It usually is, but it doesn’t have to be.

EDIT: the query I used to get the closest result was

```
Select *,
Case
    When Min(RunningTotal) 
           Over(Partition By GroupName, (RunningTotal/CutOff) 
                Order By RunningTotal, (RunningTotal%CutOff) 
                Rows Between 1 Preceding and 1 Preceding
              ) Is Null 
        and RunningTotal >= CutOff 
     Then 1
  Else 0
End as Flag
From MyTable
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the query you have tried ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’ve edited the post now to include the query I’ve mentioned. Any other form of query I’ve done has worked fine until I get to the first record above the CutOff and then it sums continuously.

Comment: If you add DDL+DML for the sample data you make it much easier for people to work on

Comment: I think row must be (G1, 2020, 125, 289, ``414``, 1) instead of ``399``? And G1 (2023, 125, 408, 414, 0)?

Comment: @ValNik you’re correct, I just got off in my counting. I’ll correct that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you what you want without using imperative logic. But it's a bit hard to comprehend, is limited by maximum recursion, and might not be any faster than simple imperative iteration. In other words, this might be one of those cases where a cursor is actually the best pure T-SQL solution.

The logic below is as follows:

The recursive CTE is, as always, composed of an anchor element, and a recursive element.

The anchor element picks up the first row for each group name, in ascending order of year, where the running total exceeds the cutoff. I use `top 1 with ties` here just because I can - no nesting required.

The recursive element then picks up the first row for each group name, in ascending order of year, from the original table where the running sum is larger than the running sum + cutoff from the prior recursive result.

I can't use `top 1 with ties` in the recursive element (`top` is illegal here), so instead I have to use a nested query and then filter it using `where v.rn = 1` to get the "top" match for each group name.

The result of the CTE will contain all of the "flagged" rows. This is then left joined onto the original table in order to mark the appropriate rows as flagged.

I have added a few extra rows to the input data, and I have interpreted "greater than the CutOff" as written in the question - strictly greater than, not greater than or equal to.

```sql
drop table if exists #t;

create table #t 
(
   groupName char(2), 
   year int, 
   cutoff int, 
   runningTotal int, 
   primary key clustered (groupname, year)
);

insert #t
values 
('G1',  2013,   50,     30   ),
('G1',  2014,   100,    95   ),
('G1',  2015,   125,    149  ), -- should be flagged
('G1',  2016,   125,    202  ),
('G1',  2017,   125,    228  ),
('G1',  2018,   125,    253  ),
('G1',  2019,   125,    273  ),
('G1',  2020,   125,    289  ), -- should be flagged
('G1',  2021,   125,    320  ),
('G1',  2022,   125,    337  ),
('G1',  2023,   125,    408  ),
('G1',  2024,   125,    600  ), -- should be flagged
('G2',  2013,   100,    42   ),
('G2',  2014,   100,    101  ), -- should be flagged
('G2',  2015,   100,    200  ),
('G2',  2016,   100,    201  ), -- should not be flagged - equal, not greater
('G2',  2017,   100,    202  ); -- should be flagged

with cte as 
(
   select         top 1 with ties
                  t.groupname, 
                  t.year, 
                  t.cutoff, 
                  t.runningTotal
   from           #t t
   where          t.runningtotal > t.cutoff
   order by       row_number() over 
                  (
                     partition by groupName 
                     order by year asc
                  )
   union all
   select         v.groupName, 
                  v.year, 
                  v.cutoff, 
                  v.runningTotal
   from           (
                     select   rn = row_number() over 
                              (
                                 partition by u.groupName 
                                 order by u.year asc
                              ),
                              u.groupname, 
                              u.year, 
                              u.cutoff, 
                              u.runningTotal
                     from     #t    u
                     join     cte   c  on c.groupName = u.groupName
                                          and c.runningTotal + c.cutoff < u.runningTotal
                  ) v
                  where v.rn = 1
)

select      t.*,
            flag = iif(c.groupname is null, 0, 1)
from        #t    t
left join   cte   c  on c.groupName = t.groupName 
                        and c.year = t.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
with t0 as(select *,row_number()over(partition by GroupNAme order by year)rn from test)
,r as(
  select rn,GroupName,Year,CutOff,RunningTotal
   ,case when RunningTotal>CutOff then CutOff+RunningTotal else CutOff end NewSum
   ,case when RunningTotal>CutOff then 1 else 0 end fFlag
   ,chNewSum,   chFlag
  from  t0
  where rn=1
  union all
  select t.rn,t.GroupName,t.Year,t.CutOff,t.RunningTotal
   ,case when t.RunningTotal>r.NewSum then t.CutOff+t.RunningTotal 
    else r.NewSum end NewSum
   ,case when t.RunningTotal>r.NewSum then 1
    else 0 end fFlag
   ,t.chNewSum, t.chFlag
  from r inner join t0 t on t.GroupName=r.GroupName and t.rn=(r.rn+1)
)
select * from r
order by groupname,rn;
```

with test data

```
create table test (GroupName varchar(10),Year int,CutOff int,RunningTotal int
  ,chNewSum int, chFlag int);
insert into test values 
 ('G1', 2013,   125,    30,     125,    0)
,('G1', 2014,   125,    95,     125,    0)
,('G1', 2015,   125,    149,    274,    1)
,('G1', 2016,   125,    202,    274,    0)
,('G1', 2017,   125,    228,    274,    0)
,('G1', 2018,   125,    253,    274,    0)
,('G1', 2019,   125,    273,    274,    0)
,('G1', 2020,   125,    289,    399,    1)
,('G1', 2021,   125,    320,    399,    0)
,('G1', 2022,   125,    337,    399,    0)
,('G1', 2023,   125,    408,    524,    1)
,('G2', 2013,   100,    101,    201,    1)
,('G2', 2014,   100,    151,    201,    0)
,('G2', 2015,   100,    251,    251,    1)
;
```

Output is

| rn | GroupName | Year | CutOff | RunningTotal | NewSum | fFlag | chNewSum | chFlag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | G1 | 2013 | 125 | 30 | 125 | 0 | 125 | 0 |
| 2 | G1 | 2014 | 125 | 95 | 125 | 0 | 125 | 0 |
| 3 | G1 | 2015 | 125 | 149 | 274 | 1 | 274 | 1 |
| 4 | G1 | 2016 | 125 | 202 | 274 | 0 | 274 | 0 |
| 5 | G1 | 2017 | 125 | 228 | 274 | 0 | 274 | 0 |
| 6 | G1 | 2018 | 125 | 253 | 274 | 0 | 274 | 0 |
| 7 | G1 | 2019 | 125 | 273 | 274 | 0 | 274 | 0 |
| 8 | G1 | 2020 | 125 | 289 | 414 | 1 | 399 | 1 |
| 9 | G1 | 2021 | 125 | 320 | 414 | 0 | 399 | 0 |
| 10 | G1 | 2022 | 125 | 337 | 414 | 0 | 399 | 0 |
| 11 | G1 | 2023 | 125 | 408 | 414 | 0 | 524 | 1 |
| 1 | G2 | 2013 | 100 | 101 | 201 | 1 | 201 | 1 |
| 2 | G2 | 2014 | 100 | 151 | 201 | 0 | 201 | 0 |
| 3 | G2 | 2015 | 100 | 251 | 351 | 1 | 251 | 1 |